# Errno 13 Permission denied Python (Using pyinstaller)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am by no means an expert, but in case someone has the same issue in the future this is what fixed my problem. I'm sure it's obvious to some people.

I was having an issue where I kept getting "Errno 13 Permission denied" when trying to write to a text file that's created into a folder on my desktop after creating an .exe through pyinstaller.

The text file name was a variable in my script set up like-

```
path = os.path.expanduser("~\\Desktop\\Folder\\")
random_name = ImportVariableFromMyOtherPyFile.random_name

final_path = join(path_to_folder, random_name + ".txt")
```

and then writing with

`file = open(final_path, 'w')`

followed by what was getting written to the text file.

This set up worked fine through python, creating a .txt file with the random name as the name of the file.

Comment: Are you running the exe in the `dist` folder?

Comment: Yes, I was running it in the dist folder. Would that create any problems or only if I took it out of the dist folder?

I added other dependencies for that script to that folder as well, I have things in that code set to look in the current working directory. Everything else worked until it got to the first write part of my code.

Comment: Yes the paths have to satisfied, so it has be placed in the working directory right?

Comment: Yes, the main .exe and things it pulled from were in that directory. The creation of the .txt file wasn't, and didn't need to be.

Comment: So it has to be in the project directory

Comment: yes, the .exe and dependencies have to be in the project directory, but that's because of how I have my code set up as far as i know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file = open(final_path, 'w+')`

Needs to be:

`file = open(final_path, 'x')`

The 'x' will create the file so the rest of the code will be able to see where it is trying to be run.

I'm self taught but if I had to guess when it's run in python, python can see that there is no file that is named 'randomname'.txt and will create the file and then be ready to write to it, where through the pyinstaller .exe version it has to be explicit? If anyone knows feel free to leave a comment.

I know this is a repeated question as well, but from what I saw the answers in those questions mainly mentioned:

Run as admin, check firewall rules, check folder permissions, run through elevated CMD.

So I just wanted to add what helped me, just in case someone is doing the same thing wrong as me in the future.

Comment: yes...i can't accept my own answer for a few days though it seems